# Deleting cache did not solve Error:create service of type TaskArtifactStateRepository

Tags: android, gradle

Building this [App](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/).
I got the following error and tried solutions for deleting chache and .gradle files folder, but it is not solved.

```
Error:Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateRepository using TaskExecutionServices.createTaskArtifactStateRepository().
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
```

build.gradle file(tried with tools version 26.~ too):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':aars')
    implementation project(':models')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: tried already. Also invalidated cache.